# "File cannot be imported because its parent does not exist." error

Tags: content-deployment

We're trying to run a content deployment job from our development server to test and it throws this error:

`The file SiteAssets/Forms/Document cannot be imported because its parent /logistics does not exist.`

We're pushing root `/` and not the Logistics site, which is a sub-site from the root, and as far as we can tell, root doesn't have any dependencies on it. Anyone know what could cause this and how to resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it a test or production environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running an import of a backup of a sub-site should be done with a user account being member of the site collection administrators group, else you get some cryptic error messages and a failure of your restore operation.